# Swf is shown too small in HTML5

Tags: html, responsive-design, embed, flash

I tried many variations but it does not work to show my Flash animation 100% (resizable).
The animation is here : http://webdesign.igorlaszlo.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/flash/site-complet/index.html

My doctype :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="no-js ie ie6 lte8 lte7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="no-js ie ie7 lte8 lte7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js ie ie8 lte8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://www.mywebsite.com/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script><![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <html lang="fr-FR" style="" class="js">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

First variation of embedding swf :

```
<embed align="middle" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" style="border:0px solid #dddddd" height="100%" width="100%" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" quality="high" src="http://www.mywebsite/index.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></embed>
```

Second variation :

```
<object>
<param name="movie" value="http://www.mywebsite.com/index.swf"/>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"/>
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="sameDomain"/>
<param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>
<embed wmode="transparent" src="http://www.mywebsite.com/index.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" class="swfObject" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" allowfullscreen="true"/>
</object>
```

Any idea ???

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body, object{width:100%;height:100%;padding:0;margin:0;}
</style>
```

Comment: you are genious, it works !!! thanks a lot... it remains to test it in Chrome, Safari and IE, i use Firefox...

Comment: finally i use only the `<embed>` code, for html5 it is enough but i did not know that we can give 100% width and height style to the object and embed tags...